# Why isn't my Rake task using the environment that I used in my Cap command?

Tags: rake, capistrano3

I'm calling `bundle exec cap staging demo:foo`.

The `demo:foo` Cap task calls a Rake task that prints out `Rails.env`.

**BUT... the Rails task is printing "development" instead of "staging" as expected.  Why is it doing that? Why isn't it using whatever environment I passed to `cap`?**

I'm aware that I can add `with rails_env: staging`, but I don't want to hardcode the env.  I want to be able to use this Cap task for multiple environments, and I want Rake to use whatever I told Cap to use.

```
### CAP TASK
namespace :demo do
  desc "run a demo command"
  task :foo do
    on roles(:app) do
      within release_path do
        execute 'pwd'
        execute :rake, 'grant:foo'
      end
    end
  end
end

### RAKE TASK (called by above cap task)
namespace :grant do
  desc "do-nothing demo task"
  task :foo do
    puts "args: #{ARGV}"
    puts "Rails.env: #{Rails.env}"
    puts "pwd: #{Dir.pwd}"
  end
end
```

Output:

```
3404 ~/dev/myblog$ bundle exec cap staging demo:foo
DEBUG[40846cbf] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /home/blog/rails_apps/blog/staging/current; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/blog/rails_apps/blog/staging/current'" 1>&2; false; fi on 172.245.32.193
DEBUG[40846cbf] Command: if test ! -d /home/blog/rails_apps/blog/staging/current; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/blog/rails_apps/blog/staging/current'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG[40846cbf] Finished in 0.815 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO[8615517c] Running /usr/bin/env pwd on 172.245.32.193
DEBUG[8615517c] Command: cd /home/blog/rails_apps/blog/staging/current && /usr/bin/env pwd
DEBUG[8615517c]     /home/blog/rails_apps/blog/staging/releases/20141031234442
INFO[8615517c] Finished in 0.230 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO[1afa8e9e] Running bundle exec rake grant:foo on 172.245.32.193
DEBUG[1afa8e9e] Command: cd /home/blog/rails_apps/blog/staging/current && bundle exec rake grant:foo
DEBUG[1afa8e9e]     args: ["grant:foo"]
DEBUG[1afa8e9e]     ENV: development       <<<<<<<<< WHY IS THIS?
DEBUG[1afa8e9e]     pwd: /home/blog/rails_apps/blog/staging/releases/20141031234442
INFO[1afa8e9e] Finished in 1.491 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

**Versions:**

- capistrano is 3.2.1
- capistrano-rails is 1.1.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I just solved it.

I added `with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do` to my Cap task.

```
namespace :demo do
  desc "run a demo command"
  task :foo do
    on roles(:app) do
      within release_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do    # ADDED
          execute 'pwd'
          execute :rake, 'grant:foo'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

At first, this strikes me as silly, because I have to tell Cap to use the env that I already told it to use.

But after further thought, it seems I am confusing deployment environments with rails environments.  In my current system, they are 1-for-1 (e.g. deployment-staging deploys rails-staging, deployment-prod deploys rails-prod), but that may not necessarily be the case in other systems.